# averaging values of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, average

I have a vector that has values for individual half hours.  I need to relate this to hourly values.  How can I take my vector with half hour values and average only two values at a time to get a new vector of averaged values?

For example, if I have the vector

```
a <- c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)
```

How can I create vector b where the first value of b is the average of x1 and x2 and the second value of b is the average of x3 and x4

```
b <- c(average of x1 and x2, average of x3 and x4, average of x5 and x6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- 1:10
colMeans(matrix(x, 2))
#[1] 1.5 3.5 5.5 7.5 9.5
```

You might want to have a look at the time series functions and packages (xts, zoo, ...).

Comment: The beautiful thing about R is there's a bunch of different ways to get something done.

Answer (score 1):

Roland's answer is a good one.  The way I've done it in the past is like so

```
a <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- tapply(a, (seq_along(a) - 1) %/% 2, mean)
```

Here's an article about tapply:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-function-of-the-day-tapply/

Good luck!